# new MobileFirst Services Starter - any location services?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'd like to create "GPS-location-aware" native app in a handy way on Bluemix.
So I was a big fan of [Mobile Location Services(beta)](http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/android#location) of MobileData,
but old "Mobile Cloud" boilerplate is gonna fade away. Then, is there any equivalent function in the new "MobileFirst Services Starter" ? Or my old ["Mobile Cloud Services SDK"](http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/index.html) works in the new "MobileFirst Services Starter" as it is ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to open a request to Bluemix Support in order to forward the the question to MobileFirst team.
Please use one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the
  upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI. After opening the support
  widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of
  assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget. Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Comment: Please do not open a support ticket immediately after posting a question here. The same team that handles support tickets monitors this forum and will only bog us down with duplicates. 

If there is an urgent problem feel free to follow the process above, but posting here will be just as fast, if not faster.

Comment: OK, then I'll wait for the response from the MobileFirst team here. Thanks

Comment: I know there is a "Submit an Idea" option underneath "support" on the Bluemix dashboard.  
  Login to Bluemix --> dashboard --> select profile (far upper right hand corner)

However I have not had any experience with it, I am still waiting for a response from my team.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no location service for the new Mobile Services Starter, however as I suspected, the best way to make a feature request is the use the 'user voice' feature. This can be found in the top right menu (profile) -> submit an idea.

A team of managers from all the offerings meets regularly to review what comes in through that channel and turn it into a backlog for the product.